# Multiple concurrent ssh connections with robot framework

Tags: ssh, process, nodes, robotframework

How do I use Robot Framework to have multiple ssh processes running? All to different nodes on a cluster. I have though of using a for loop, or using start process keyword in process library to start one for each of the nodes I need. I need to check the OpenSSH_ version on each of these nodes.

I'm very new to robot framework.

```
@{nodes}   Create List     1  2  3  4   5   6   7   8
    :FOR    ${node}   IN   @{nodes}
    \  Open Connection    ${node}
    \  Enable SSH Logging    ${output}
    \  Run Keyword And Ignore Error     Login  user    pass
    \  Log     all output:${output}
    \  File Should not be empty     ${output}
    \  ${version}=     Grep File      ${output}   OpenSSH_
    \  Should contain  ${version}  OpenSSH_6.9
    \  Close Connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SSHLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Connections%20and%20login) library for Robot Framework supports multiple connections to different hosts. Ideally, you will end up with something like this:

```
:FOR    ${host}    IN    @{hosts}
    Open Connection    ${host}
    Comment    Do something with current ${host}
    Close Connection
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what @{hosts} means. I have used SSHLibrary though! Just didn't know it could be used for concurrent connections. One by one would be too slow.

Comment: @Kepler `@{hosts}` in this case would be a list of all your hosts.

Comment: Hm.. i made a list and it is only checking the 1st host in that list. host are numbers as placeholders. Not actually putting numbers :)
Code is added to the question.

Comment: @Kepler I have the same issue. it's only checking 1st host. How did you solve it ?

Comment: This is not working. it only handles the first host on the list. This is especially true if you start passing commands with Execute Command

Answer (score 1):

Switch between the different SSH session with the below keyword :

```
Switch Connection    index_or_alias
```