# RobotFramework SSHLibrary AttributeError with public key authentication

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to connect  to a linux CentOS server using Robotframework SSHLibrary

But, I'm getting an error. `AttributeError: Raw`

I'm trying to use an authentication with public key. Below is the Robotframework code and screenshot and the debug log of ssh

Robot framework code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SSHLibrary    

*** Keywords ***
Connect to SSH

    Open Connection    ${ipServer}    
    ${output} =    Login With Public Key    ${username}    ${publicKeyFile}     
    Should Contain  ${output}   Last login at 
    Log    ${output}
```

[image: _]
**SSH debug log**

```
> /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 22 
> debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL
> 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:KQzAdsluR6UNzkc1OFUIMoXGvovgsIXNwLSVPc8fnec debug1: private
> host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
> SHA256:IPsIS6YeMse5AhkrSL/hpbCLwLJaZL6P3Jae/0/4ndo debug1: private
> host key #2: ssh-ed25519
> SHA256:lROO9MgwSVKargW43Q6umRrXxLuIjgCmlw+K1D/BJrI debug1:
> rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd' debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d' debug1:
> rexec_argv[2]='-p' debug1: rexec_argv[3]='22' debug1: Set
> /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000 debug1: Bind to port 22 on
> 0.0.0.0. Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22. debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::. Server listening on :: port 22. debug1: Server will not fork
> when running in debugging mode. debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock
> 5 pipe -1 sock 8 debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3 Connection
> from 172.16.172.1 port 58668 on 172.16.172.131 port 22 debug1: Client
> protocol version 2.0; client software version paramiko_2.6.0 debug1:
> no match: paramiko_2.6.0 debug1: Local version string
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol
> 2.0 debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth] debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth] debug1: list_hostkey_types:
> ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
> [preauth] debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth] debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth] debug1: kex: algorithm:
> curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth] debug1: kex: host key
> algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth] debug1: kex: client->server cipher:
> aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth] debug1: kex:
> server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
> [preauth] debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
> [preauth] debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
> [preauth] debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
> Connection closed by 172.16.172.1 port 58668 [preauth] debug1:
> do_cleanup [preauth] debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
> debug1: do_cleanup debug1: Killing privsep child 7800
```

Comment: Check this, and similar google-found issues - https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1472. The error comes from somewhere in paramiko & it's supporting libraries (this is the underlying python ssh client library used by RF's one). You're running in some version incompatibility issue.

Comment: @TodorMinakov I wish i knew how you found this answer. i'd have never found it. upgrading cryptography solved the issue. This should be an answer. Thank you Todor

Comment: Glad it did; for reference, I just searched for "python ssh" "AttributeError: Raw"".

Comment: @TodorMinakov yes. first hit on google. I'll try to emember using quotes on keywords groups like to did. Also, do you you know why FOR loop only hits the first host in the list like this guy did ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235867/multiple-concurrent-ssh-connections-with-robot-framework I can only get Execute Commad to work for the first host on the list and then the test suite shuts down